# Two files with the same name in the same folder

Tags: windows

I just notice that I have two files with the same name in the same folder:

[image]

How is this possible? I checked the properties as suggested [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/2-files-exactly-same-name-in-same-folder/9c7628de-bc1a-48c8-a369-6a74da1ed4c4) but the "Location" is actually the same... I am able to open both files and move them to the same directory without any problems... What's going on? Does this mean my hard disk is failing or something?

Comment: There is going to be a difference in the filenames. I expect the `é` character to be different in both filenames, or it can be the classic small L versus big i. In order to find out what the case is, try a `dir /x` in command prompt to see what's going on

Comment: It's perfectly possible to represent an `é` in several ways in unicode, and these ways would show up as different files. So some application wasn't doing unicode normalization properly...

Comment: did dir /x and got this: https://i.imgur.com/W8ehduI.png It seems like the accent on the e in the first one is a separate letter from the e so the names are actually different. That's weird. Thanks

Comment: Voted +1 on the question. I don't see why this needs a negative vote.

Answer (score 2):

There is going to be a difference in the filenames. I expect the é character to be different in both filenames, or it can be the classic small L versus big i.

In order to find out what the case is, try a dir /x in command prompt to see what's going on.

In the comments you gave the result of the dir /x command which hielded:

[image]

This clearly shows that indeed the é character is represented differently causing 2 different files.